# Why does the sample HelloCpp cocos2d-x example have special logic for windows

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am using cocos2d-x v2.2.3. In the HelloCpp example, in HelloWorldScene.cpp, there is this line for setting the design resolution:

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WINRT) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WP8)
    pEGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, kResolutionShowAll);
#else
    pEGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, kResolutionNoBorder);
#endif
```

Why is windows treated differently compared to other platforms ?

EDIT: I have only iOS and Android devices at present, and windows is the last platform I will develop for, but I don't want to paint myself into a corner before that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking except why is the design resolution a bit different? `kResolutionShowAll` on Windows and `kResolutionNoBorder` everywhere else.

Comment: Yes. Why does the example choose to have a different resolution strategy just for windows?

Comment: I'm sure because Windows does things a bit differently. You could file a bug report and ask for clarification on why. http://cocos2d-x.org/issues/

Comment: My theory is that the WinRT implementation of every other resolution project is terribly flawed and bugged so they literally *cannot*.  I'm trying as well to get the no border policy into my app but am being met with graphical glitches.